# ReactJS – TextArea onChange Not Triggering on iPhone only

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, textarea, onchange

I have a text area that updates a value in state when it is typed in and displays the new value in the text area.  Very simple, and works fine on desktops and android phones, but it doesn't work on iPhone.  On iPhone, I type and nothing happens (there's also no cursor).

**My textarea**

```
<div>
   <h3>Notes</h3>
   <textarea name="notes" value={this.state.notes} onChange={(e) => this.handleTextChange(e)}></textarea>
</div>
```

**Function to change value in state**

```
handleTextChange = (e) => {
    console.log("triggering handleTextChange...");
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      changesWereMade: true
    });
  }
```

I have also tried various approaches:

```
<div>
  <h3>Notes</h3>
  <textarea name="notes" value={this.state.notes} onChange={this.handleTextChange}>{this.state.notes}</textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Notes</h3>
  <input name="notes" value={this.state.notes} onChange={this.handleTextChange} />  // this does work on iPhone, but I need a textarea
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Notes</h3>
  <textarea name="notes" value={this.state.notes} onChange={(e) => this.handleTextChange(e)}></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Notes</h3>
  <textarea name="notes" value={this.state.notes} onChange={(e) => this.handleTextChange(e)}>{this.state.notes}</textarea>
</div>
<form id="noter-save-form" method="POST">
  <textarea id="notes-text-area" name="notes" value={this.state.notes} onChange={(e) => this.handleTextChange(e)}></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

---

**EDIT**

Also tried the following changes:

*Textarea change*

```
<div>
  <h3>Notes handleNoteChanged</h3>
  <textarea name="notes" value={this.state.notes} onChange={this.handleNoteChanged}>{this.state.notes}</textarea>
  <textarea name="notes" value={this.state.notes} onChange={this.handleNoteChanged}></textarea>
</div>
```

*Function to change value in state change*

```
 handleNoteChanged = (e) => {
    console.log("triggering handleNoteChanged...");
    alert(e.target.name, e.target.value);
    const name = e.target.name
    console.log("name = " + name);
    const value = e.target.value
    console.log("value = " + value);
    this.setState({
      notes: value
    });
  }
```

---

**Does anyone understand why I can't type in the `textarea` on iPhone but can on everything else?**

Comment: try to add `alert(e.target.name, e.target.value);` in handleTextChange and check it on your iphone. btw. Don't do this (e) => this.handleTextChange(e), just this.handleTextChange. Don't do this `[e.target.name]: e.target.value` extract them out of setState by constants

Comment: I tried these changes but no luck.  (edits above)

Comment: @Rbar Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score -1):

use `onInput` instead of `onChange`

```
<textarea ... onInput={(e) => ...}></textarea>
```